# How to show text in blackberry in other languages?

Tags: blackberry, fonts, font-family

I want to show malayalam script in my application in blackberry 5.0.i tried with following code. but it shows text in english only.

```
      try {
         alphaSerifFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Serif");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

     Font appFont = alphaSerifFamily.getFont(Font.MALAYALAM_SCRIPT, 9, Ui.UNITS_pt); 
     setFont(appFont);
```

Comment: Did you tried the Ressource files in JDE? (I mean .rrc and .rrh files)

Comment: no. i have no idea about it. please give me any links that explains how to use these files. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links:

http://yamspog.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/how-to-use-resource-files-in-your-blackberry-app/

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Create_resource_file_for_BlackBerry_Application_655978_11.jsp

When done with creating the ressource files, use the following code to retrieve the KEY value:

```
public static ResourceBundle _res = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_ID, BUNDLE_NAME);
_res.getString(yourKey)
```

Comment: thanks farid. I work with it. hope it will leads to solution.

Comment: It will if your aim it to display the text in different languages.